# why is this if statement met in my script? JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, math, random

I am just doing something really simple to check if the random number is over 9999 since I am trying to make a random return between 0 - 9999 so I am having a for loop to do a simple if test to run through but somehow even if the number is not 9999 it still went into my if statement and console of the number.

What is it that I am missing here?

```
function setHiddenFields() {
    let answer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
    // console.log(typeof answer);
    return answer;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 9999; i++){
    if(setHiddenFields() > 9999){
        console.log(setHiddenFields()); // returns 4389
    }
}
```

It is random, sometimes it shows 8167 or just random numbers that is not bigger than 9999 and still `console.log` the number...

Comment: You call the `setHiddenFields` 2 times in your loop, and they do not need to return same value. That's why your `if` statement won't work.

Comment: If you want random number in [0, 9999], you should use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)`, and should not plus one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a radom twice times, one for if-statement, and then another on for output.
That's how your code running:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 9999; i++){
    if((Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1))> 9999){
        console.log(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1)); 
    }
}
```

That's what you actually what:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 9999; i++){
    var output=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000)) + 1;
    if(output> 9999){
        console.log(output); 
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG how can I miss that point! this is embarrassing, usually I would assign a variable to it oh my my thx thx for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Store the result in variable first.

```
   for (let i = 0; i < 9999; i++){
        var result = setHiddenFields();
        if(result > 9999){
            console.log(result);
        }
    }
```